# Correct mongo database is not picked up from the connection parameter, instead have to map it manually

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I am having an issue where I need to manually map the correct database to the domain instead of it being picked up from the connection argument.
I am using grails 3.2.8, plugin "org.grails.plugins:mongodb:6.1.0". I have both hibernate and mongodb plugin enabled.

I have define my connection URL as

```
//application.yml     
   mongodb:
      url: 'mongodb://${MONGODB_USERNAME}:${MONGODB_PASSWORD}@${MONGODB_REPLICA_SET}/${MONGODB_DATABASE}?${MONGODB_CONNECTION_OPTIONS}'
```

My domain object is defined as :

```
class ReportData {

    String id
    Long someField

    static mapWith = "mongo"
    static mapping = {
        //database "db-name" DOESN'T WORK WHEN COMMENTING OUT THIS LINE
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the database(system property MONGODB_DATABASE) be picked up auto-magically from the connection url? I am not sure if this is a bug or I am missing some configuration aspect.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I had not added following in my build.gradle file:

```
bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

so my application environment settings were not even getting applied correctly and hence my connection url was invalid.

I found that detail here: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html